# JS function not getting called inside string html in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, infowindow

I am using string html and there is an image in it. I have to call onclick function on it. Onclick function works but for alert only. when I call a JS function it doesn't get called. I have used this.bind, arrow function and every possible way but no result. It is in react, pasting only relevant code here:

```js
import pic1 from '../../assets/img/1.png'

class MapModule extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: null,
      redirect: false,
      store:props.latlng,
      toggleFlag: false
    };
    this.Toggle =  this.Toggle.bind(this);
  }
  
  Toggle () {
    alert('Clicked');
    
  }
  
  let content1 = `
        <div class="opacityEffect">
          <img width=100% onclick=${this.Toggle} src=${pic1}>
        </div>`;
        
  // This in event on infowindow for google maps
  marker.addListener('click',function () {
    map.setZoom(22);
    map.setTilt(45);
    infowindow.setContent(content1)
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```

PS: Everything runs fine, its 200 lines of code. Onclick of map marker infowindow gets open. Now I want to open a new window onClick of infowindow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your template literal converts the function to a string, it doesn't *refer* to the function. You'll have to set the content in a way that doesn't use a string. (I don't know `infowindow` so I don't know what that would be.)

Comment: "I am using string html" — Don't. You're using React. Make this a proper component. Return some JSX from the `render()` method.

Comment: The thing is it is the only way for it according to the scenario. And alert gets called and an outer JS variable too get shown inside the alert. But function is not working. Ignore infowindow, just clarify how to call JS function inside string literal html

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code, you used a normal HTML onclick event to call the React function. In React JS, the syntax of onclick event is as shown below.

```
<button onClick={activateLasers}>
   Activate Lasers
</button>
```

As I observe, you need to use the "C" in onclick. I have had the same issue when I am first working on Riot.js and it fixed when I changed to lowercase letters.

And I don't think you need to use "this" inside React events.

Comment: May be you can use render() function in React to render HTML instead of using it on string.  or to use dynamically, you can use nested components also.

Comment: @JohhnyDev you can’t mix html strings and react like this.

Comment: Any examples please ?
I have used component approach too but infowindow requires only html string or node as content.